# Error importing a GeoTIFF in GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine, geotiff-tiff, import

I have uploaded an asset as GeoTIFF and added it into the script and used these lines:

```
var input = ee.Image.loadGeoTIFF('users/parivash89/Eucalyptus_Brazil/mean_WinterIC_SaoPaolo_Float-0000000000-0000000000_ExtractedByBuffer_ExtractedByClass9')
Map.addLayer(input, {min:0,max:3000,bands:"B4,B3,B2"}, "Winter_tile1_Extracted" )
```

It gives the error:

> Winter_tile1_Extracted: Layer error: Image.loadGeoTIFF: Invalid GCS URL: "users/parivash89/Eucalyptus_Brazil/mean_WinterIC_SaoPaolo_Float-0000000000-0000000000_ExtractedByBuffer_ExtractedByClass9". Expected something of the form "gs://bucket/path/to/object".

I have shared the asset and here is the code:
https://code.earthengine.google.com/c83da25eab833a137533dacbe5ba7007

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use `ee.Image.loadGeoTIFF()`, it's the wrong method and your image is already loaded. You can either use `input` directly (i.e. skip line 1 entirely) or if you want to hardcode it into your code, then the correct syntax is:

```
var input = ee.Image('users/parivash89/Eucalyptus_Brazil/mean_WinterIC_SaoPaolo_Float-0000000000-0000000000_ExtractedByBuffer_ExtractedByClass9')
```

Comment: Thank you so much @M. Nicolas.